# declaring submethod on function, __call__, can't be called after definition

Tags: python

```
>>> def f():
...        def __call__(x):
...             return x
... 
>>> f(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
>>> f.__call__(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

The problem is that upon defining `f` and its private subfunction `__call__`- and thence after attempting to call the function (with the thought that it'd call the `__call__` override instead) it throws an error that states the function doesn't take any arguments, yet one was passed.

And (obviously- in hindsight) trying to call the `__call__` method, it gives the exact same error.

On this, I'm confused as I thought that firstmostly, `f` would be defined, then it'll have its basic private methods created (like `__str__`, `__name__`, `__repr__` etc.) and then the definition of the explicit `__call__` method would replace the implicitly generated `__call__` method.

Can somebody explain either what the order of function definition is and what gets declared first and last, or explain how you would manage to override the hidden `__call__` (preferably, if possible, without using a class to mask a function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace in a function does not produce attributes. `__call__` is a *local variable* inside `f()`, nothing more.

`def <identifier>(...):` binds the name `identifier` in the *current namespace*, and in a function that means it assigns a local name, just like `some_name = ...` would do.

At most, you can return that object:

```
>>> def f():
...     def __call__(x):
...         return x
...     return __call__  # return the local variable
...
>>> f()
<function f.<locals>.__call__ at 0x10e946400>
>>> f()(1)
1
```

It would be really surprising if all local variables in a function became attributes instead, even before you had actually executed the function!

However, even if you gave a function object a `__call__` attribute, *it still would not be used*. You can only use a *class* to create an object with a `__call__` method:

```
class Foo:
    def __call__(self, x):
        return x

foo = Foo()
foo()  # returns 1
```

That's because `__call__` is a *special method*, and thus subject to the [*Special method lookup* rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup), which dictate that Python would look for the method on the type of the object, not the object itself.

When Python evaluates `foo(...)`, if `foo` is not a function object Python will execute `type(foo).__call__(foo, ...)`. Python does this to make sure that the `Foo.__call__` method is not used when you create your instance with `Foo()`; classes are callables too but defining `Foo.__call__` should not clash with that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to avoid is what `__call__` is for. It allows an *object* with the method to masquerade as an function. When you're defining a function, you're not creating an object with properties - there simply is no method named `__call__` defined (.. that you've defined yourself, at least) on the object representing the function `f`.

However, it turns out you already have a function that handles your call, namely `f`. You can also use decorators to wrap that function if necessary, or as you've suggested, create a class and instanciate an object instead.